# limit offset with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to construct a mysql query that lets me search for products constrained by a subquery (sizes) AND have an offset to allow for pagination on the site.

A url could look like this:

```
http://www.[webshop].com?category=shirts&size=m&page=2
```

The following query works ONLY IF the offset is 0 (e.g. page=0)

```
$limit = 50;
$offset = $page * 50;

SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT * FROM sales WHERE sale_id IN (SELECT sales_sizes.sale_id FROM sales_sizes WHERE sales_sizes.size = '.$size.') '.$search_string.' ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$offset.') s)
LEFT JOIN sales_sizes ss ON s.sale_id = ss.sale_id
LEFT JOIN sales_images si ON s.sale_id = si.sale_id
LEFT JOIN sales_prices sp ON s.sale_id = sp.sale_id
```

**How would you implement a limit offset in this case?**

It MUST have a subquery constraint, so I can return products of a certain size.

Comment: If you put the `LIMIT...OFFSET` clause at the end of the sentenca?

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit = 50;
$offset = $page * 50;

SELECT *
FROM sales s
  INNER JOIN sales_sizes ss ON s.sale_id = ss.sale_id
  LEFT JOIN sales_images si ON s.sale_id = si.sale_id
  LEFT JOIN sales_prices sp ON s.sale_id = sp.sale_id
WHERE ss.size = '.$size.'
ORDER BY ss.created_at DESC 
LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$offset.'
```

There's 2 syntaxes for the LIMIT clause:

```
LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}
```

The second syntax that you're using was included for compatibility with PostgreSQL. Could try the first incase something odd is happening, but the documentation says it's fine!